# combination of 5 identical capacitors

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electricity, capacitance

Given 5 identical capacitors, each EMF.
Draw the proper combination of all these 5 capacitors..
1.) 2.5 
2.) 4.17

I really do not know how to solve this thing and if anyone of you knows the title of this lesson please comment it here so I can study it further.  We will be having our finals tomorrow.

Answer (score 1):

ok you might know how to add the resistor's in series and parallel so adding capacitor's is just opposite to that

so all the capacitors are of same capacitance so when you add them in series they add up like
$\frac{1}{C_t}$ = $\frac{1}{C_1} + \frac{1}{C_2}+...+\frac{1}{C_5}$ and when you place them in parallel they add up like$C_t = C_1 +C_2 + C_3 + C_4 +C_5$ so now you can try all the combination and reach to the answer